# run the same function when nav link is clicked (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am redesigning my site and one of my goals is getting off the jQuery library. Vanilla JS has proved a tougher challenge than I hoped for. I need to prevent the nav links from going to a different page and run a function. heres what I have so far but not even the preventDefault is working. Please help!

```
$navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
$navlinks.onclick = function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  this.blur();
  //function here
}
```

Comment: thanks @CertainPerformance for pointing me to the right direction I will post answer soon!

Comment: $navlinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');
    for(i = 0; i < $navlinks.length; i++)  with $navlinks.onclick inside the loop